# Find a special integer coefficients polynomial which takes small absolute value on [0,4]

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, inequalities

The question is easy to state: Is there a non-constant $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that for all $x\in [0,4]$, we have $|f(x)|\leq 1$? I do not know where to find a useful reference for it.
I did a few tries, and the best I can get is some variation of $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$, which could take a small value when $0.72<x\leq 4$. I can also show that there does not exist such a $f$ for $[-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},4]$, but it is probably a bad estimate.

Comment: I would be interested to know the idea for the proof of the $[-1/\sqrt 2,4]$ result!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. Integer coefficients are a red herring; the point is that, if $f(x) = f_n x^n + \cdots + f_0$ is a real polynomial with $f_n \neq 0$, then the $L_{\infty}$ norm of $f(x)$ on an interval of the form $[a, a+4]$ is at least $2 |f_n|$. So, if $f_n$ is a nonzero integer, this is $\geq 2$.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Minimal_.E2.88.9E-norm) for the analogous result for $L_{\infty}$ norm on $[-1, 1]$. To deduce the corresponding formula on $[0,4]$, make the change of variable $y = 2x+2$ and keep track of the powers of $2$.

Comment: The red herring does suggest the follow-up question: What is $M=\inf\|p\|_{L^{\infty}(0,4)}$ when we minimize over non-constant $p\in\mathbb Z[x]$? Your answer shows that $M\ge 2$, but presumably $M>2$.

Comment: In fact, it's still $M=2$. To see this, define the polynomial $T_n$, monic of degree $n$, by $T_n(z+1/z)=z^n+1/z^n$. Note that $T_n$ has integer coefficients. Then put $z:=e^{i\theta}$, giving $T_n(2\cos\theta)=2\cos(n\theta)$. Thus $|T_n(x)|$ is bounded by $2$ on $[-2,2]$. Hence $|T_n(x-2)|$ is bounded by $2$ on $[0,4]$. (Note that $T_n$ is closely related to the standard Chebychev polynomial $t_n(x)$, which is defined by $t_n(\cos\theta)=\cos(n\theta)$.)

Comment: @Chris76 How can I extend your result for arbitrary intervals $[-B, B]$? Is it still the case, for larger intervals, that the real-coefficients and integer-coefficients case have the same lower bound?