# Existence of an integer coefficients polynomial with prescribed bounds on [0,4]

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Is there a polynomial f with integer coefficients that satisfies the following criteria:

1. f is not constant;
2. for all $x\in[0,1]$, $1-\frac{1}{x}\leq f(x)\leq \frac{1}{x}$;
3. For all $x\in [1,4]$, $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$.

Comment: We have $f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4) \in \{0, 1\}$, so there are at most 16 possibilities to $f(x) \mod (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$. This modulus must also have integer coefficients (because $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$ is monic), and checking all the possibilities, it must be either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Because $f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)$ must actually be extrema, we can get the value $\mod (x-1)^2 (x-2)^2 (x-3)^2 (x-4)^2$

Comment: @Yanlong Hao Doesn't the technique in David Speyer's answer of your very similar previous question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458834/ apply here?

Comment: @PeterMueller Thanks for asking. The $L_\infty$ bounds here is $\infty$. Even considering the function g(x)=xf(x), the possible $L_\infty$ bounds after shift down is possible close to 2.5. Hence it is related but does not answer the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $g(x)=x\cdot(f(x)-\frac{1}{2})$. Then the maximum of $\lvert g(x)\rvert$ on $[0,4]$ is at most $2$. From [David Speyer's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458834) of a similar question and the reference given there, it should follow that $g(x)=2T_n(\frac{x}{2}-1)$, where $T_n$ is the Chebyshev function of degree $n$, and $n$ is the degree of $g$. However, $g(0)=0$, while $-1$ is not a root of $T_n$. So there is no such $f$.